# User Profile Properties Not Importing?

Tags: user-profile-service, user

Here's the scenario:
I add a user to Sharepoint under 
Central Administration : Manage User Profiles

The Name, Email and Manager come over, but not the Office (mapped to PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName) or Company or Department.

*Why is that*? Shouldn't it sync?

Comment: Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise on-prem.

Comment: That sync requires a User profile synchronisation connection to be setup and ran, has that been done?

Comment: Are those fields configured to be fetched in the user profile service application. If yes I'll suggest you to run a compete synchronization.

Comment: There is a nightly sync process and these fields are in it.